# Reading Image using OpenCV2 gives matrix full of zeroes?

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to read image as matrix in Python using OpenCV library but when I read the image & display it as matrix , it shows the matrix full of zeroes .

I beleive there is some error , as Image is carrying some content in it .
Below is my Code( Python3) :

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("truck_icon.png",0)
print(img)
```

Below is the link for the image I am using : 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6NSt.png)

Could you help me out in this issue ??

Comment: No,  It shows `0` and `255` for me.

Comment: Are you viewing it in jupyter notebook ?? or what

Comment: Could you try out the above image ( I have changed the image in post )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is `PNG` with alpha channel. So if you just read with flag `0`(that is `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`), then your result may be different with your expected.

Better way is to read the `PNG`(contains alpha channel) with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag. Then calculate the region value(, may be roi op is ok).

```
img = cv2.imread("truck_icon.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
b,g,r,a = cv2.split(img)
cv2.imshow("B", b)
cv2.imshow("G", g)
cv2.imshow("R", r)
cv2.imshow("A", a)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

This is the source image:

[image]

After splitting the channels to `B-G-R-Alpha`:

[image]

---

This is another `PNG` with alpha:

[image]

The responding `B-G-R-Alpha` channels:

[image]

---